# SQL Transactions - two inserts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, unique-constraint

I wrote a SQL procedure that inserts data into two tables. I started with `begin transaction` but some data violate constraint of second table and in the end data are added into first table, but not in second. What is wrong with my code?

```
create procedure [dbo].[procAddConference]
    @Conf_name varchar(50),
    @Begin_date date,
    @End_date date,
    @Price money,
    @Student_disc numeric(3,2),
    @Limit int,
    @Disc numeric(3,2),
    @Until int 
as 
    set nocount on
    begin transaction;
    begin try
        IF (@Begin_date > @End_date or @Limit < 0 or @Disc <0 or @Disc >1 or @Student_disc < 0 or @Student_disc > 1)
        BEGIN 
            ; throw 52000, 'Wrong data', 1
        END

        insert into Conferences (ConferenceName, BeginDate, EndDate, Price, StudentDiscount)
        values (@Conf_name, @Begin_date, @End_date, @Price, @Student_disc)

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        begin
            RAISERROR('Error, transaction not completed!',16,-1)
            rollback transaction;
        end     

        declare @confID INT
        set @confID = @@IDENTITY

        declare @duration int
        declare @iterator int
        set @duration = DATEDIFF(dd, @Begin_date, @End_date)
        set @iterator = 0

        while @iterator <= @duration
        begin
            insert into ConferenceDay (ConferenceID, Date, Limit) 
            values (@confID, cast(DATEADD(dd, @iterator, @Begin_date) as date), @Limit)

            IF @@ERROR <> 0 or @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            begin
                rollback transaction;
                RAISERROR('Error, transaction not completed!',16,-1)
            end

            set @iterator = @iterator + 1
        end

        commit transaction;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @errorMsg nvarchar (2048) = 'Cannot add conference . Error message : ' + ERROR_MESSAGE () ;
        ; THROW 52000 , @errorMsg ,1
        rollback transaction;
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: sorry, sql server management studio 17 ;)

Comment: Your  transactions command  is not proper with exception handling

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Also, if you're kind to yourself and add a tally/numbers table into your database, there's no need to write a *loop* just to generate (effectively) a sequence of numbers and perform individual inserts. Better yet, a calendar table would allow you to directly query for the set of dates and eliminate both the loop and the date maths.

Comment: maybe the `commit transaction` should be after the catch? And the final `rollback` before the throw?